$H = \mathbb{Z}_6\times\mathbb{Z}_{15}/ \left<(0,3)\right>$ is isomorphism to which group?
If $ H = \mathbb{Z}_6\times\mathbb{Z}_{15}/\left<(0, 3)\right>$ , then $H$ is isomorphic to which group?
I know the order of $H$ is $18$.
Every element of $H$ can be represented as $(a,b)+(0,3k)$, where k is $0,1,2,3,4$.
